# d3.js array issues: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

My data is:

```
var data = {"january":[{"total":"31","date":"2015-01-01"},{"total":"19","date":"2015-01-05"},{"total":"4","date":"2015-01-10"}],"error":false,"status":200};
```

The error occurs on:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
```

I know I'm accessing the array incorrectly, but I'm unsure how. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your array of data is actually in the `january` property of your object ... You'll need to go through that property to get the data you're interested in.

Something like this:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data.january[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data.january[data.january.length - 1].date), 1)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the array in wrong way.

```
 var data = {
        "january": [
            {"total": "31", "date": "2015-01-01"},
            {"total": "19", "date": "2015-01-05"},
            {"total": "4", "date": "2015-01-10"}
        ], "error": false, "status": 200
    };
```

`date` property is actually inside the `january` property, So you have to access it first. Then select the index, because january property has an array with multiple elements.

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([new Date(data.january[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data.january[data.january.length - 1].date), 1)])
            .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
```